Mockito test for a method with modelandview parameter
I need to write junit cases for a method like below.
protected void redirectToHomePage(String storeId, String langId, String catalogId, ModelAndView modelAndView, String topCategoryId, HttpServletRequest request) {
        

        StringBuilder viewName = new StringBuilder();
        viewName.append("Redirect:StoreView?Id=190");
    
       modelAndView.setViewName(viewName.toString());
        
}

My test class looks like this.
public class ANFCategoryDisplayBrowsingViewControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void TestRedirect() {

        ANFCategoryDisplayBrowsingViewController categoryController = new ANFCategoryDisplayBrowsingViewController();
        MockHttpServletRequest mockRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        categoryController.redirectToHomePage("10051", "-1", "10901", modelAndView, "10001", mockRequest);
        
        assertEquals( "Redirect:StoreView?Id=190",modelAndView.getViewName());


    }
}

But my modelandview is always returned as null but it while running the test it goes inside the method and sets the viewname. Can someone help with this please?
Thanks

Is the modelAndView instantiated before being passed to the redirectToHomePage method or is it null?

Is modelAndView a mock?  If yes, then calling a method on the mock, .e.g. modelAndView.getViewName() will return null (unless the mock was setup to return something).  For this test, probably should verify(modelAndView).setViewName("Redirect:StoreView?Id=190"); (instead of the assertEquals).

Yes, modelandView is a mock and it is not set up with anything

Thanks everyone for your suggestions. It helped a lot.
